# Problema con Google Maps e Ionic 2. Falta plugin

Tags: google-maps, angularjs-2.0, cordova, ionic2

Buenas,

Estoy tratando de mostrar un maps de Google Maps en mi app en Ionic2.

Me está dando por consola los siguientes warnings:

> Native: tried accessing the GoogleMap plugin but it's not installed.
>
> Install the GoogleMap plugin: 'ionic plugin add plugin.google.maps.Map'

Ya he añadido teoricamente el plugin con esta instrucción.

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_API_KEY_IS_HERE"

De hecho si la vuelvo a ejecutar me da el mensaje:

*Plugin "cordova-plugin-googlemaps" already installed on android.*

No se que más hacer. He seguido paso a paso tutoriales de todo tipo y color. Y no hay forma de que aparezca el mapa.

El código:

Component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'location-page.html'
})
export class LocationPage {

    private map: GoogleMap;
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,private platform:Platform) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.setupGoogleMap()
       });
    }

    setupGoogleMap(){
    // somewhere in your component
    try{
        let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(40.409202,-3.732649);
        this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
            'backgroundColor': 'white',
            'controls': {
                'compass': true,
                'myLocarionButton': true,
                'indoorPicker': true,
                'zoom': true
            },
            'gestures': {
                'scroll': true,
                'tilt': true,
                'rotate': true,
                'zoom': true
            },
            'camera': {
                'latLng': location,
                'tilt': 30,
                'zoom': 15,
                'bearing': 50
            }
        });
       this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
           console.log('Map is ready!');
       })
    } catch(e){
        e => console.log(e);
    }

  }
    latitud: number = 40.409202;
    longitud: number = -3.732649;

}
```

component.html

```
<ion-content>
  <div id="map"></div>
  </ion-content>
```

Código después de intentar el enlace: https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html

```
export class LocationPage {

    private map: GoogleMap;
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}

        lat: number = 51.678418;
        lng: number = 7.809007;
```

HTML:

```
<ion-col>
      <sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
        <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
      </sebm-google-map>
      </ion-col>
```

Sigue sin funcionar a pesar de que ya no da error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que este plugin es **nativo** es decir, sólo se puede ver en un dispositivo móvil, pruébalo con tu celular conectándolo a tu computadora y correlo con

```
ionic run android
```

o

```
ionic run ios
```

debes ver el mapa correctamente.

Sí necesitas la guía para probarlo paso a paso dependiendo de tu dispositivo, ve al siguiente link de ionic 2: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/cli/run.html

Recuerda que sólo se ve en tu dispositivo real, no en cualquier emulador.

Cualquier problema relacionado con tu api key, ve a la página: angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html donde te explica como conseguirla y aplicarla a tu proyecto.

Comment: Si, lo leí y lo cargue a mi movil precisamente con lo que comentas. `ionic run android` Pero ni con esas. Si necesitas información adicional dímelo.

Comment: Primero haz lo siguiente: `ionic platform remove android` y `ionic platform add android` ya que aveces al estar desactualizados esos plugins puede que no funcione tu mapa y después utiliza la siguiente página para configurar tu api key ya que de la otra manera (una para android y otra para iOS) en lo personal nunca me funcionó: https://angular-maps.com

Comment: De hecho en este link de la misma página te explica cómo se genera una sola api key: https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html e instalar su plugin, con eso a mi me funcionó, además trae un ejemplo en código, si aún no puedes, dime y te muestro mi código de mi ejemplo (de hecho ya no necesitas correrlo en un dispositivo, puedes verlos en tu navegador ya que no es un plugin nativo).

Comment: Voy a probar y te cuento.

Comment: Nada @Juan-Hernández no hay manera. He añadido abajo de la pregunta el código de el enlace pero nada.

Comment: Vale, nada me faltaban los estilos. Puedes editar tu respuesta poniendo el enlace que has pasado y así marco tu respuesta como correcta?.  @Juan Hernández

Comment: Gracias @Findelias